# What's the &: part in a closure argument list?

Tags: closures, rust

Look at the code:

```
let add_one = |&: x| { 1 + x };
```

I know `x` is the closure argument, but what is the meaning of  `&:` in the closure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an underdocumented (and **obsolete**, see comment) section of Rust right now. The best reference I know of is the blog post [Purging proc](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/):

> Because the current inference scheme is limited, you will sometimes need to specify which of the three fn traits you want explicitly. (Some people also just prefer to do that.) The current syntax is to use a leading `&:`, `&mut:`, or `:`, kind of like an “anonymous parameter”:

```
// Explicitly create a `Fn` closure.
foo(|&:| { ... })

// Explicitly create a `FnMut` closure.
foo(|&mut:| { ... })

// Explicitly create a `FnOnce` closure.
foo(|:| { ... }) // (ERROR)
```

> Caveat: It is still possible we’ll change the `&:`/`&mut:`/`:` syntax before 1.0; if we can improve inference enough, we might even **get rid of it altogether**.

And it looks like it was removed in [#21843](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21843)! Thanks for pointing that out, @swizard!

Comment: As I understand, according to #21843 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/21843 this syntax is now obsolete.